# How to call a function when a variable changes in an API

Tags: javascript

I am calling an API and updating the objects variables on interval.
Within the updateAPI function I wanna check if the variable increases and if it does I wanna call a function.

I have tried setters and getters, storage and other methods. Also played around a lot with different variants of current code but I can't understand the other solutions.

```
function updateAPI() {
  var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
          callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
          callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  };
  getJSON('api.example.com',  function(err, response) {
    if (err != null) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      let data = response.data
      var followers = data.followers_count
      var old = followers;

      function check() {
        if (old > followers) {
          console.log('changed');
          var old = followers;
        }
        if (old < followers) { 
          console.log('not changed'); 
          var old = followers; 
        }
      }
      setInterval(check, 5000);

    }
  });
}
updateAPI();
setInterval(() => { updateAPI() }, 10000);
```

The current code does not log any changes happening to the API. But I can console.log('followers') and see the value changing.

Comment: Isn't followers and old are same  "var followers = data.followers_count
var old = followers;". I suggest to pass the old and new value as parameters to check(). Any reasons for using 2 setInterval()?

Comment: I concur with @Ajay `old === followers`

Comment: i setinterval for the API to update the values and one to check if the value has changed

Comment: setInterval for updateAPI is good but I suggest to shift the check() out of internal setInterval() and remove the setInterval as the check() will automatically get invoked after each successful API completion.

Comment: `setInterval(() => { 
  if (old > followers) {
    console.log('changed');
    var old = followers;
  }
  if (old < followers) { 
    console.log('not changed'); 
    var old = followers; 
  }
  updateAPI() 
}, 5000);` 
can i do this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Just some minor things to start:

Move `getJSON` outside and above of `updateAPI`. Right now every time it gets called, it is creating a new function which isn't needed. Also you can probably just replace it with the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). You can also abstract the `check` function and allow it to accept an argument (or two) and tell you if you should update.

Secondly have your tried debugging this some how? Either using `console.log` statements or the Chrome debugger? The problem lies in this code:

```
var followers = data.followers_count
var old = followers;
```

`followers` and `old` will *always* be equal. You're re-assigning them every time you call your function. That is why you're seeing it change, but never seeing it log anything.

Comment: Well yeah. As I said it doesn't log the strings in the check function. But it does log the changing value.

Comment: Right, but have you tried using `console.log` else where, perhaps earlier in the function to check the variable values that you're comparing? If you do, I be you'll spot the error we've pointed out very quickly.

Comment: i don't know how to check for the value change... the followers === old so right now it's pointless.

Comment: You said:

> But I can console.log('followers') and see the value changing.

The very next line, you set old = followers and then compare them. They will always be equal because you set them equal to each other _every_ time.

Comment: i wanna call a function when it changes. so i need to find a way to detect if it has changed.